# Video file is not readable when trying to upload

Tags: video, htc-one, troubleshooting, uploads

I recently downloaded a zip file with two .mov video files in it. Once I unzipped the file onto my Android phone (HTC One), I converted the file using a Media Converter app. I can play the file on a VLC player, but when I try to upload it to any social media (Instagram and Facebook), it doesn't even show up as an option. What can I do to change that? I need it to be able to upload in this fashion for work and have been trying to do this for the last 24 hours with no luck. Any suggestions please???

Answer (score 0):

Convert the files to a recognized format like MP4 or 3gp

Comment: That's what I did. For some reason, even though I converted it to an mp4, it still won't read as an option when I want to post it online.

Comment: sometimes it's the media scanner... Try moving it to a different location like the internal storage and restart the device

Comment: I moved it to five different locations and rebooted it. I'm starting to get frustrated 

Comment: go the old fashion way... Upload to YouTube and share the link, It'll change to a video link, Then delete the text and post it :)